# Unpack the list and put as variable

Tags: python

I have source code like this

`chain` accept the multple number of lists.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3]
list3 = [1,2,3]

chain(list1,list2,list3)
```

However I want to treat `list1 list2 list3` as one list and put this in chain

```
total = [list1,list2,list2] 

chain(total) # it doesn't work , ochain doesn't accept the list.
```

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: ```total = list1 + list2 + list3
```

Comment: @dekishigrash for me your code works perfectly maybe it depends on the version of python you are using.

Comment: The only thing missing is a `*`: `chain(*total)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```py
from itertools import chain

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
list3 = [1, 2, 3]

total = [list1, list2, list3] 
result = chain.from_iterable(total)
```

```py
>>> list(result)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working.

```py
from itertools import chain

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3]
list3 = [1,2,3]

print(list(chain(list1,list2,list3))) # you need to convert chain object to list.
```

There is a simple way using pure python.

```py
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3]
list3 = [1,2,3]

output_list = list1+list2+list3
print(output_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. it is also the good practice for python generic way. I use `chain.from_iterable` this time though.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to do this (without extra lib):

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3]
list3 = [1,2,3]

result = [*list1,*list2,*list3]

print(result)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```